# javascript confirm dialog keeps appearing sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I'm using confirm dialog to ensure a user action. But the confirm dialog keeps appearing again and again while I don't see in my code anything which is triggering this. Is it a bug? or am I doing something wrong?

```
$('#table_trans tbody').on('click', 'tr td button', function() {
    var trans_id = $($(this).parents(':eq(1)')[0].childNodes[0]).html();
    var r = confirm("Sure!");

    if (r == true) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '?r=transactions/ajaxdelete',
            data: {
                id: trans_id
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $.notify(response, "error");
            }
        });
        $($(this).parents(':eq(1)')).remove();

    } else {
        alert("Action Cancelled!");
    }
});
```

One more thing to add, It happens only sometimes that the Javascript confirm dialog keeps appearing. sometimes it behaves correctly, sometimes it appears twice, but sometimes infinitely.

**UPDATE**

As suggested by Parag Bhayani, Here is the javascript that adds a row to the table `#table_trans`

//  `msg` is  a json response received by making an ajax call

```
for (var i = 0, l = msg.length; i < l; i++) {
                    var rowz = "<tr><td>" + msg[i].id +"</td><td>"+msg[i].account_no+"</td><td>" + msg[i].date_of_transac +"</td><td>"+msg[i].description+"</td><td>"+msg[i].amount+"</td><td><button id=\"delete_trans\">Delete</button></td><tr>";
                    tbl_html = tbl_html + rowz;

            }
```

// sorry for the discomfiture .... but please scroll to extreme right to see the button, clicking which is triggering the event.

Comment: how is it appearing when clicking on confirm?did you add all relevant code to OP?

Comment: How many times this confirm appears?
would you also send the code from where this event is registered?

Comment: Here, one case that could be causing this issue, if this event registeration code is in loop then your event might have registered n number of times, and that could be causing this issue

Comment: @ramesh-pareek can you post a demo on jsfiddle ?

Comment: Great Parag Bhayani.. You helped me sort it out thanks. In fact the event is triggered from a button in a table row.  And the table row is generated dynamically based on the number of records for that particular transaction in the database. so may be when I find the dialog is appearing 'infinite' times, the number of rows being generated are simply too many. Anyhow. thanks for helping me figure it out.

Comment: I suspect that you have miss attached the event handler on an unintended element, i would need to see the html in order to help you out, so please either make a JSFiddle or add the html code here.

Comment: The code is a bit complicated. I will simplify the code to make a jsfiddle relevant to the question.

Comment: @RameshPareek Okay I am pasting this as an answer...

Comment: thik hai parag ji.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be happen only if your event is registered multiple times, so one case for that could be causing this issue is that, event registeration code is in loop then your event might have registered n number of times.

Comment: Kindly add example about my code in the light of the update that I've made. because StackOverflow doesn't allow accepting before 8 minutes :)